# Why browser XHR send() does not receive 408 server error while uploading, but cURL does

Tags: javascript, ajax, timeout

We intend to gracefully kill an upload request sent from Browser, particularly for slow connections. In server code we send [408 Request Timeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/408) after **3 minutes** and discard the request data.

While testing the API we realized that **cURL** if throttled in speed will **behave as expected**, but while testing Browser **Ajax calls** for upload if the connection is throttled in Chrome they will **not abort**, **nor receive server's response** while it's sending data.

We know how to set timeout on the client side. However, I am interested to know why **browser's Ajax calls do not respect server's response while sending data**. And if there is anyway to make it **behave as consistent as cURL**?

I tried to create a reproduction example in gist using a simple nodejs app in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/nimatrueway/0068b9a182176fdfc285b1c66aa2292b) if you'd like to try for yourself.

Comment: You need the `Connection: close` header

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Lk77, I tried it now. It didn't work.

Comment: With curl i get the timeout after 1 minute

Comment: I think at that point express already responded with a `HTTP/1.1 100 Continue` so it's too late, i think you will have to change the timeout

Comment: With or without `Expect` header cURL works, it receives the response and closes the connection on time. However, browser is still sending data over the throttled connection while server has responded and closed the connection (I guess). 

I added a screen recording to the comment of my gist reproduction.

Comment: I don't think this behaviour is consistent then, because it does not work with curl for me, connection is closed at 1m4s each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ajax calls use `fetch` API of browsers that are currently `half duplex`. Bowsers do not support `full duplex` yet.

> To allow streams to be used in a request, the duplex request option needs to be set to 'half'.
>
> In browsers, the response never becomes available until the request body has been fully sent, even if the server sends a response sooner. This is true for all browser fetching.
>
> In future, duplex: 'full' may be supported in browsers for streaming and non-streaming requests.
>
> https://developer.chrome.com/articles/fetch-streaming-requests/